# WFS works only in IE browser. Any work around is available for this issue?

Tags: wfs, ux, browser, chrome

WFS works only in IE browser for me.

It's not working in any other browser. I don't have much expertise in  checking browser compatibility, could someone suggest me how to resolve this issue or if any workaround is available for this issue to make it works in Mozilla and Chrome also.

Comment: and many other questions - search for WFS and Proxy for a full set